# Digital Micrograph - Callback to return a custom image on CameraAcquire() method

Tags: events, callback, dm-script

I'm doing some automation tests with Digital Micrograph and I would like to return a custom image from a specific folder when acquiring an image. I couldn't find a clear event in the documentation. Is there a way to add a callback to CameraAcquire method?

For example, if I run this:

```
number camID = CameraGetActiveCameraID()
image img1
CameraPrepareForAcquire(camID)
img1 := CameraAcquire(camID)
ShowImage(img1)
```

The *img1* would be set to my custom image, instead of what CameraAcquire(camID) would normally return.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you can use the OpenImage function in place of CameraAcquire in your automation test script. You can find details about this function in the Scripting > File Input and Output section of DM's on-line help (accessed via the Help > Search menu command). OpenImage takes only one argument, a string containing the file path to your custom image. If you want your script to prompt you to locate and select the custom image file (instead of hard-coding its file path), you can use the OpenDialog function. An example of its usage is given in the Scripting > Example Scripts > Files section of the on-line help.

Comment: Hi Mike. Yes you got it right. The caveat here is that I can't change the script (of course, if this is the only way I will try to do it). My idea is to put some event listener or callback in GMS, running in the background, that acts when the camera acquisition finishes, replacing the result image with my custom one.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Minor comment. "OpenImage()" is a somewhat wonky command only still present for legacy reason. Saved files really are ImageDocuments and should be opened as such using NewImageDocumentFromFile().  OpenImage() will work (for simple images saved), but it will only load the Image object, not the ImageDisplay! Hence one can loose things like annotations or color schemes.

Comment: @Fabio You can't add callbacks for Camera, but you can attach EventListeners for images getting frontmost, and - on newer GMS - for ImageDocuments being shown for the first time. You can use such an event and then look at the image's tags to find out if it is a new camera-image and then you can act on that. Not sure if this is helpful for your aim.

Comment: @Fabio Building on the suggestion of BmyGuest, if it is possible for you to make the Image object that receives the camera readout a persistent one (i.e. create and show the image outside the context of the above code snippet) and then have the camera data transferred to it via direct assignment (i.e. img1 = CameraAcquire(camID)), then you can detect the camera readout by using the "data_changed" event on the Image object. I have used this approach to do live update of annotations on images acquiring data in "Preview" mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @BmyGuest and Mike. I see that it's not possible to have a callback for the camera acquisition itself, but I think I can manage to change the scripts and make usage of your suggestions regarding event listeners.